# ini4j Read File Error

Tags: java, exception, ini4j

I am trying to use ini4j. But I am not able to read the file. The code:

```
ini = new Wini(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("./setup.ini"), "UTF-8"));
```

But it is giving me the errors:

```
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type InvalidFileFormatException
Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
```

I already tried "C:\setup.ini" and "setup.ini" and "C:/setup.ini"
I also tried:

```
ini = new Wini(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(New File("./setup.ini")), "UTF-8"));
```

The Variable ini is properly declared:

```
Wini ini;
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Windows .ini file

```
[main]
window-color = 00ffff
splash = true
[others]
version = 0.1
developer = Jim
```

Reading from .ini file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
import org.ini4j.Wini;


public class Main {

 public static void main(String args[]){
  try{
   Wini ini;
   /* Load the ini file. */
   ini = new Wini(new File("config/settings.ini"));
   /* Extract the window color value.*/
   int windowColor = ini.get("main", "window-color", int.class);
   /* Extract the splash screen status. */
   boolean splashScreen = ini.get("main", "splash", boolean.class);

   /* Show to user the output. */
   System.out.println("Your default window color is: " + windowColor);
   if(splashScreen){
    System.out.println("You have your splash screen activated.");
   }else{
    System.out.println("You have your splash disabled.");
   }
  } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("Invalid file format.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
  }
 }

}
```

Writing to .ini file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
import org.ini4j.Wini;


public class Main {

 public static void main(String args[]){
 Wini ini;
 try {
  ini = new Wini(new File("config/settings.ini"));
  ini.put("main", "window-color", 000000);
  ini.put("main", "splash", false);
  ini.store();
 } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid file format.");
 } catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
 }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks! The missing try catch block was the major issue!